# Comment only with a specific role and not dm

Tags: discord.js

I want a comment to only work if the author has a specific role. How can I do that? Also, I don't want to write the comment in dm's what is still working. Thanks in advance!
Kind regards

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by comment, but to check if a member has a role use this:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("INSERT ROLE ID HERE");
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return message.channel.send("You need the required role to use this!");
```

Also, just check if `message.guild` is `null` to see if the command is being used in a DM.